# MacOS 10.12 (Sierra) - Missing "SystemCACertificates.keychain" file

Tags: keychain, macos

I upgraded to Sierra today and it appears that the "SystemCACertificates.keychain" file no longer appears in Macintosh HD -> System -> Library - Keychains.

Anyone know a workaround for this?  I use a smart-card to login to many sites and I no longer have access to 50% of those sites now.  I think this might be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently being discussed here: [Centrify LInk](http://community.centrify.com/t5/Centrify-Express/SystemCACertificate-keychain-not-on-system/td-p/25231) and it seems like many of us are in the same boat.  I found a link to the certificates:  [SystemCACertificates from git site](https://github.com/aosm/security_certificates/tree/master/BuiltKeychains), and I am able to import it into my keychain.  However, the icon for the original SystemCACertificates is still in my keychain.  Also, I've notice that the most recent certificate in that SystemCACerts is CA30; my CAC card requires a CA32 certificate for validation.  Both of these issues may be to blame for why it doesn't work.  I'm planning on going back to 10.11.